# mysql innodb stopwords' role and priority in boolean mode

Tags: mysql, innodb, stop-words

I have two problems. I'm using mysql innodb full index with ngram parser.
1st. I don't know how stopwords work with ngram parser
I have customized stop words table and I set it to the parameter "innodb_blah blah".
I thought stop words would be ignored in search string wherever they were placed, but I'm confused now.
'은','는','이','가' are stop words.
MATCH.. AGAINST ( search string in boolean mode)
search string: '는무시한다'
result : same as typing '무시한다'
search string: '무시한다는'
result : empty because there're no rows '무시한다는' included.

how stop words work in boolean mode with ngram parser?

2nd. priority in boolean mode
Ley me say I typed "정전 용량"
The results would be three cases.
the one with "정전", the one with "용량", and the one with "정전" and "용량".
The problem is, "match against score" doesn't put the last case to the first.
I want AND case on the top, but it gives more score to the row which have more 'counts' (maybe tf-idf) regardless of the case two words are both appeared or not.

I'm Korean so my English is bad.
I want somebody to help me.

Comment: I guess you are familiar with [this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search-ngram.html). Also, you should know that FULLTEXT scoring works strangely when your tables are small. Just when you're testing things and trying to figure them out!

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: I don't remember now but it starts with 8.0.~